# setData does not set attributes values

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute, programmatically

I am creating simple products and try to set some attribute values

```
$attributeSetId = $product->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
$product->setSku($sku); // Set your sku here
$product->setName($product_title); // Name of Product
$product->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId); // Attribute set id
$product->setStatus(0); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0, disabled by default

$product->setWeight(10); // weight of product   

$product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
$product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
$product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
$product->setPrice($product_price); // price of product
$product->setStockData(
    array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => $qtyAvailable
    )
);
echo "Qty: ", $qtyAvailable, "\n";
foreach ($options_list as $current_option) {
    $attributeCode = $current_option["attribute_code"];
    $attributeValue = $current_option["option_code"];
    if ($attributeCode == 'color') {
            $product->setColor($attributeValue);
            echo "Color ";
    } else {
            $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
    }
    echo "Setting attribute: ", $attributeCode, " ", $attributeValue."\n";
}
$product->save();
```

I have created 2 product attributes in the backend, `color` and `shipsfrom`.
I have added these attributes to the default set.

As you can see in the code I am trying different methods to add the attribute value to my product, `setColor` or `setData`.

The values in my options array are as follow:

```
attributeCode    attributeValue
color            White
shipsfrom        Spain
```

However neither color nor shipsfrom got any value assigned to them after product creation, while all other  standard attributes do get values assigned properly.

Am I using the wrong methods to update these attributes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many try attempts I finally made it work:

setData was not working with option code, but was with option ID.
I modified the code as following:

```
foreach ($options_list as $current_option) {
        $attributeCode = $current_option["attribute_code"];
        $attributeValue = $current_option["option_code"];
        $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
        $value = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($attributeValue);
        $product->setData((string)$attributeCode, $value);
        echo 'Setting ', $attributeCode, ' to ', $attributeValue, "\n";
    }
```

Also important to note, $product-save(); is not the right way anyore in magento, instead you should use the productRepository:

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
...
$product = $productRepository->save($product);
```